# Kubernetes: How to delete namespace based on age/creation time

Tags: kubernetes

Is it possible to delete namespace in kubernetes based on creation time or age?

Example : I would like to delete all namespaces with specific name which are older than 3 day.

Comment: With help of shell/bash yes, quite similar to [the answer in your another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68893998/15537201)